# Kernel panic libcryptsetup.so.12 missing, once upgrading to 18.04

Tags: boot, upgrade

I selected OS upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 LTS. Update encountered error and reported that system might be unstable. After trying to reboot I get kernel panic complaining about missing libcryptsetup.so.12. 
The issue here is I don't know how to access my home folder using live CD (home folder is in LVM volume which is crypted) -or is it even possible... I can see the uncrypted volume in /dev/mapper (after cryptsetup luksOpen )and mount it, but the home folder is empty (except .Private and that stuff). 18.04 doesn't have ecryptfs-recover-private like previous releases, if I boot using liveCD 17.10 and try to use  ecryptfs-recover-private nothing happens, expect permission denied messages while access gvfs files. Please any idea how to fix this?

Regards,
J

Comment: `libcryptsetup.so.12` is part of the `libcryptsetup12` package.  Is that package installed?